# Не удается поместить картинку в центр круга

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, выравнивание

Не удается поместить картинку в центр круга.. Решить отступами не предлагать - это не профессионально, картинка может быть любого размера

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: table;
}
img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1 вариант**

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 71px;
}
img {  
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
</div>
```

**2 вариант**

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;  
}

.circle-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-item">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
  </div>
</div>
```

**3 вариант**

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;  
}
img {  
  position: relative; top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); 
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); 
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
</div>
```

**4 вариант**

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

И еще один вариант:

```css
.circle {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.36em;
}
.circle img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="http://40years.issn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logotype_40th_anniversary.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="На воде" data-category="На воде">
</div>
```

P.S. У вас изображение масштабируется не пропорционально. Может установить для него `max-width: 40px` или `max-height: 40px`, а атрибуты ширины и высоты убрать?

Comment: нет, нельзя картинки могут быть любые по размерам и нельзя их сжимать-растягивать. `margin-right: -0.36em;` это конечно не айс, с отступами я писал, что не вариант я и сам знаю как

Comment: @Вася что-то по поводу "`margin-right`" и "не айс" я не понял. Впрочем, это уже не имеет значения.

Comment: ну, насколько я понимаю за счет `margin-right` у вас позиционирование достигается - разве оно универсально для всех размеров картинки?

Comment: @Вася, теперь понятно, что вы имели в виду )) Объясняю: между элементами `inline-block` есть текстовые узлы. Именно поэтому, вы можете наблюдать между такими элементами "отступ". Для того, чтобы этот отступ убрать, существуют разные приёмы: писать их без переноса на новую строку, использовать html-комментарии, `letter-spacing: 0;` или, как сделал это я. Только в одном я ошибся в спешке: не `margin-right`, а `margin-left: -0.36em`. *0.36em* - это максимально приближенное значение ширины того самого текстового узла.

Comment: @Вася И кстати, на счет универсальности - используя такой способ, не нужно учитывать ширину родительского элемента и ширину дочернего (*центрируемого*) элемента.